# Getting Count on Number of Instances in Array (subtracting after continue; statement in loop)

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a 'Pricing History Table' based off MySQL table.
Because we have a lot of alike listings, a lot of these entries appear as duplicates, aside from of course the ItemID.

Here's how I'm currently weeding out duplicates (not really duplicates, but similar  listings that have the same SKUs, Y-m-d Date, Previous Price, New Price and Sales Channels. -- and also trying to get a count (see $count logic below) of how many alike/"duplicate" rows were found)

```php
$inventoryhistoryrows = array();

$skuarray = array();

foreach ($pricehistoryarray as $ph_key => $ph_values) {

// defining variables, etc.
. . . . . 

$ph_sku_timestamp = $inventoryskus . ' ' . $ph_timestamp . ' ' . $ph_previousprice . ' ' . $ph_newprice . ' ' . $ph_channel;

if (in_array($ph_sku_timestamp, $skuarray)) { continue; }

$skuarray[] = $ph_sku_timestamp;

if(isset($prev)) {
    $newcount = $count - $prev;
    $prev = $count;
}
else {
    $prev = $count;
    $newcount = $count;
}
```

$inventoryhistoryrows[] = array($newcount, $ph_itemid, $inventoryskus, $ph_previousprice, $ph_newprice, $ph_channel, $ph_timestamp);

This is working.... but my `$newcount` is always one row ahead!

Here's an illustration of output in table:

[image]

Note the arrows on the far left side. The $newcount variables are correct but the entire first column needs to moved up by one row.

Meaning, `1` should be removed from the first row. `3` Should be in the first row. `17` Should be in the second row.

I can of course see that the reason why 1 is showing up in the first row is due to this statement

```php
else {
    $newcount = $count;
}
```

Meaning it will always return 1 for the first row, as `prev` does not exist. But I simply put this there as I was unsure of a proper way to get the data as I wanted.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do this? In the initial foreach loop for `$pricehistoryarray` (I suppose this would be the better solution), or a relatively simply method for shifting up only the first column once the `$inventoryhistoryrows` array is constructed?

Comment: What is `$newcount` supposed to be ?

Comment: Can't you directly do that filtering using SQL? With a `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Cid Noticed I didn't explain this but made a quick edit after I posted..... -- and also trying to get a count (see $count logic below) of how many alike/"duplicate" rows were found)

Comment: Well, `COUNT(*)` along with `GROUP BY` does it well (as long as you don't need the `ItemID`)

Comment: `GROUP BY` as far as I know will not tell me how many other like rows were found. I suppose I could look into MySQL query solutions, but was hoping I could get a quick fix in my loop (as it seemed I was close -- again, it's giving the results, just one row off for the `$newcount` --- just saw your edit... I'll check that out

Comment: [Yes it can](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFcdpbmfNteL8vB9iiCT1T/0)

Comment: Thank you. See edits. Resolved!

Comment: Don't post your solution in the question. You'd rather write an answer

Comment: Note for the future that everything that can be done SQL-side should be done there. If you get a set of result and re-treats it on backend to fits your needs, you are already doing it wrong. Doing it SQL side reduces bandwith usage and backend time of execution. Think [green !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_computing)

Comment: Thank you, yes. I was not aware I could use COUNT(*) to get a count of GROUPed rows, so that was my blindspot. Makes sense, you are correct, noted :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this might be better off in the MySQL Query (see comments)

This seems to be working

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
     , itemid
     , previousprice
     , newprice
     , channel
     , timestamp 
  FROM listing_price_history 
 WHERE listing_price_history.timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)     
 GROUP 
    BY previousprice
     , newprice
     , channel
     , DATE(timestamp) 
 ORDER 
    BY listing_price_history.timestamp DESC
```

Big thanks to @Cid for the guidance

Comment: Glad you were able to answer your question. Note that if an unaggregated column appears in the SELECT, then it MUST also appear in the GROUP BY. Anything else just leads to trouble.